# MobileFirst REST Services API to administer the runtime environments is not working as expected

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server

I am using MobileFirst Platform 6.3.0.00-20141218-1823

I tried to leverage some of the MobileFirst server's [Rest Service administrator APIs](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_6.3.0/com.ibm.worklight.apiref.doc/apiref/c_restapi_oview.html) like updating the [device status](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_6.3.0/com.ibm.worklight.apiref.doc/apiref/r_restapi_device_status_put.html) for the devices associated in the MobileFirst server. As per IBM Knowledge Center,

> A device can be marked as active, lost, stolen, disabled, or expired.
>   Lost, stolen or disabled devices cannot access the server.

I am able to update the device status to **LOST** and then tried to access my mobile application, where it connects to MobileFirst server and retrieves data from it (contradicts with the information in Knowledge Center).

Are there any pre-requisites that should be configured in the MobileFirst Server to make this work as expected?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to configure a security realm, see [User to Device Mapping and Control](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_6.3.0/com.ibm.worklight.monitor.doc/monitor/c_device_user_mapping.html?lang=en), and you need to modify server properties as described in [Enabling the device access management features](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_6.3.0/com.ibm.worklight.monitor.doc/monitor/t_enabling_device_access_mgmt.html?lang=en). The parent topic, [Mobile Application Management](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_6.3.0/com.ibm.worklight.monitor.doc/monitor/c_device_mgmt.html?lang=en), should help give you an overview of the whole process. Hope that helps.